# Streaming join multiple resultSet

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I have a problem about sql performance, my db is too many rows, so this make long time to query.

```
SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON A.id = B.id where ...
```

So I change to

```
SELECT * FROM A where A= a...
SELECT * FROM B where B= b...
```

I got 2 resultSet from 2 query here.
Can someone help me how to join 2 resultset with the best performance.
I have to split to 2 query because this database have 10 mil records.

Comment: It is unlikely that you can write a better join than the join implementation in your database.

Comment: If you want help tuning a SQL query, you should ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/, where you can ask about [*Advanced Querying* including window-functions, dynamic-sql, and **query-performance**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I can parse 2 resultset to hashmap and join with the key, O(n) will be 2n, better than join sql n^2

Comment: SQL engine can do hash join, merge joins, nested loop joins, etc. and they are likely better optimized too. All you need is the ability to tune the SQL.

Comment: I'm using mysql, as i know, mysql doesnt support hash join :(

Comment: Now that is important information, don't you think? Edit the question and say that, e.g. by tagging with `mysql`. See also: [Is there any way to force MySQL use Hash Join instead of Nested Loop Join?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/43439/127602)

Answer (score -1):

```
Select col1, col2 ...
from 
    ( 
    -- first query
    ) as tab1 
join 
    (
    -- second query
    ) as tab2 on tab1.colx = tab2.coly
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference?

Comment: i don't think that it will give the huge performance improvement, but when we joining the small stables,i thought it may give somewhat better performance. because here we perform the query to select the only relevant rows using where clause in each table separately and then perform join. this is better than joining all the rows first and using where clause to filter it out. please correct me if i'm wrong.